# Punctuations while using "since he has been here"

Tags: punctuation, commas, since

Which of these sentences are correctly punctuated?

> a. Since he has been here he has been behaving strangely.
> b. Since he has been here **,** he has been behaving strangely.
> c. Since she is a doctor he will know the answer to your question.
> d. Since she is a doctor **,** he will know the answer to your question.

In the first two 'since' has a temporal meaning and in the second two it means 'because'.

Comment: Except for the asterisks, which are probably artifacts of the formatting, all of them are correctly punctuated. I gather you are intending to ask about the commas, though you didn't mention them. And you're correct about the meanings of _since_ in these sentences.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wanted to put the commas in bold, but that is the way the site formats bold letters. I wanted to see if the commas change anything. Apparently they don't. Am I correct?

Comment: They're complete clauses, so it's ok to break up the sentence there with a comma. It can make longer sentences easier to read, and in this case it implies a kind of audible pause, which you might introduce if you were saying the sentences out loud. That can add emphasis to the clause before the comma, encouraging the reader/listener to think about it for a moment.

Comment: Commas never change anything. They occur only in writing, which is a bad representation of real (spoken) English, and they should be used to represent intonation curves, when they occur in speech. One such is the distinction between restrictive and non-restrictive relative clauses; non-restrictive clauses normally require comma intonation. After short introductory clauses, the speaker may or may not use comma intonation. If they do, insert the comma. If they don't, don't.